# Multiple lists plot joined lines with scattered points

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have two lists:

No.1 
[total](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3to3y0d075v1xzl/total.csv?dl=0)

No.2 
[data5](https://www.dropbox.com/s/90s948ape9qhdpy/data5.csv?dl=0)

I want to plot these two lists in one graph with a shared log-log scale.

```
option = {PlotLegends -> {"total", "data5"}, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 20], PlotRange -> All, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold], ImageSize -> {600, 400}, 
   AxesLabel -> {Style["Area[\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(mm\), \(2\)]\)]", 
      20], Style["Cluster number", 20]}, 
   TicksStyle -> Directive[Bold, 20], 
   PlotStyle -> ColorData[1, "ColorList"], Joined -> True, 
   PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 15}};
p1 = ListLogLogPlot[{total}, option]
p2 = ListLogLogPlot[{total, data5}, option]
```

The joined line for "total" is different in p1 and p2. 
For p1, there are no scattered points; but for p2, some scattered points appeared. I don't know the reason. Could anyone help me explain and solve it? 
Thank you!

The plots for p1 and p2 can be reached here:
[p1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/buq5r70l8vyapz0/total.JPG?dl=0) and [p2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pyhi379iy3sow4g/total%20and%20data5.JPG?dl=0).

Comment: The reason you get the gaps is that for `ListLogLogPlot` with the `Joined -> True` option only neighboring points with numeric values are connected.  You have lots of values of `Indeterminate` because you have zeros in your data and the log of zero results in `Indeterminate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get the gaps is that for `ListLogLogPlot` with the `Joined -> True` option only neighboring points with numeric values are connected. You have lots of values of `Indeterminate` because you have zeros in your data and the log of zero results in `Indeterminate`.

But there also seems to be other funny business with `ListLogLogPlot`.  Here is a plot of the first 4 data points from each set of data:

```
total = {{3.549425730917573, 0.005090023013401922},
  {3.9494257309175733, 0.0060647082712873964},
  {4.349425730917574, 0.041613645593610395},
  {4.749425730917573, 0.298578583998917}};

data5 = {{3.8393956761241834, 0.0024330900243309003},
  {4.239395676124183, 0.}, {4.639395676124184, 0.2116788321167883}, 
  {5.039395676124183, 0.45742092457420924}};

ListPlot[{total, data5}, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 15}, PlotRange -> All,
  ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> {"total", "data5"},
  PlotLabel -> "Raw data"]
```

[image: Raw data]

All 4 points from each dataset show up fine.  Now perform a `ListLogLogPlot`:

```
ListLogLogPlot[{total, data5}, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 15}, PlotRange -> All,
  ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> {"total", "data5"},
  PlotLabel -> "ListLogLogPlot with Joined -> False"]
```

[image: LogLog plot not joined]

We see that the second point from `data5` is missing (as one of the coordinates is zero) but also the first point from `data5` is plotted twice:  once with the marker from `total` and again with the marker from `data5`.  I can't explain that.

When we add `Joined -> True`, then we get the following:

```
ListLogLogPlot[{total, data5}, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 15}, PlotRange -> All,
  ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> True, Joined -> True, PlotLegends -> {"total", "data5"},
  PlotLabel -> "ListLogLogPlot with Joined -> True"]
```

[image: LogLog plot with Joined option]

We see that the first point from `data5` is shown with the marker from `total` but not with a second marker from `data5` and is not connected to the third point because the second point has a zero coordinate (removed automatically because taking the log in a log-log plot results in `Indeterminate`.

But such weirdness goes away if the zero values are removed or changed to some positive number.